# React native flatlist not showing output

Tags: android, react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native flatlist to display data on my react native app. but I am not getting output. the idea is to render the URLs inside the array to the flatlist. I can't find where is my error. here is my code :

```
      componentWillMount() {

        imageUrls[0] = 'https://fashionphotography.advertroindia.co.in/uploads/fashionphotography/updates/32138/product-photography-workshop.jpg';
        imageUrls[1] = 'https://fashionphotography.advertroindia.co.in/uploads/fashionphotography/updates/32138/product-photography-workshop.jpg';

      }


      renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (<View key={index}>

        <Text>{item}</Text>
                        <Image
                          style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 5}}//imageUrls[0] 
                          source={{ uri: item}}>
                        </Image>
                      </View>)

      }

      <ScrollView vertical={true}>
                        <View>
                          <Image
                            style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 5}}//
                            source={{ uri: imageUrls[1] }}>
                          </Image>
                        </View>

                        <FlatList
                    data={(imageUrls, 1)} 
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    numColumns={1}
                  />
                    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: try replacing data={(imageUrls, 1)} with data={imageUrls}